# Expansion in a non-orthogonal basis in infinite-dimensional space

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces

The functions
\begin{align}
\psi_n(x)= e^{-x^2/2} H_n(x)/\sqrt{2^n n! \sqrt{\pi}}
\end{align}
where $H_n(x)$ is the $n$'th Hermite polynomial, form a complete set of orthonormal function over the real line in the sense that for any function $f(x)$ we have
\begin{align}
\int dx \psi_n(x)\psi_m(x)&=\delta_{mn}\, ,\\
\hat {\mathbb{I}}&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\psi_n(x)\, \int dx \psi_n(x)\, , \tag{1}\\
f(x)=\hat{ \mathbb{I}} f(x)&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \psi_n(x) c_n\, , \tag{2}\\
c_n&=\int dx \psi_n(x)f(x) \tag{3}\, .
\end{align}
These functions appear as eigenfunctions of the [quantum harmonic oscillator Hamiltonian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator#Hamiltonian_and_energy_eigenstates).

Suppose instead I choose a "basis" of functions of the type
\begin{align}
\phi_n(x)= e^{-x^2/2} x^n \sqrt{\frac{2^n}{\sqrt{\pi} (2n-1)!!}}
\end{align}
so that
\begin{align}
\mathbf{S}_{ij}=\int dx \phi_i(x)\phi_j(x)&=\frac{2^{\frac{1}{2} (i+j-2)} \left((-1)^{i+j}+1\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2} (i+j+1)\right)}{\sqrt{\pi } \sqrt{(2 i-1)\text{!!} (2
   j-1)\text{!!}}}\, ,
\end{align}
with $\mathbf{S}_{ii}=1$,
so the set functions $\{\phi_n(x),n=0,\ldots,\infty\}$ is no longer orthogonal.

**Q:** How does one write the equivalent of (1),(2), (3) for the $\phi$ functions?

I thought of computing $\mathbf{S}^{-1}$ and using
\begin{align}
\hat {\mathbb{I}}&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\phi_n(x)\,  \mathbf{S}^{-1}_{nm} \int dx \phi_m(x)
\end{align}
because
\begin{align}
\phi_i(x)&= \sum_{n,m=0}^{\infty}\phi_n(x)\,  \mathbf{S}^{-1}_{nm} \int dx \phi_m(x)\phi_i(x)\, \\
&=  \sum_{n,m=0}^{\infty}\phi_n(x)\,  \mathbf{S}^{-1}_{nm}\mathbf{S}_{mi}\, ,\\
&=\sum_{n }^{\infty}\phi_n(x)\, \left( \mathbf{S}^{-1}\mathbf{S}\right)_{ni}=\phi_i(x)\, ,
\end{align}
but this displaces the problem to one of computing $\mathbf{S}^{-1}$.  To compute $\mathbf{S}^{-1}$ one could use the formal series
\begin{align}
\mathbf{S}^{-1}=(\mathbb{I}+\mathbf{K})^{-1}=\sum_{p}(-1)^{p} \mathbf{K}^p \tag{4}
\end{align}
where $\mathbb{I}$ is the "identity matrix" in the infinite-dimensional space and
\begin{align}
\mathbf{K}_{ij}=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
\mathbf{S}_{ij}&i\ne j\\
0&i=j\, .\end{array}\right.
\end{align}
but the series does not converge.

Comment: I haven't finished reading your question, but the first recommendation that comes to mind is to try the same problem in finite dimensions first.

Comment: @runway44 in finite dimension it's trivial as there is no problem with the inverse of $\mathbf{S}$.